# x.509 certificate with user credentials

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, ipad

I need to speak to a webservice which uses a X.509 certificate with user credentials (so the certificate needs the user credentials to work).

Is it possible with the iPhone SDK to use a X.509 certificate with user credentials? And if so, how do I use it? ASIHTTPRequest an option?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: anyone who can help me with this?